# Sass - Error Installing

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, sass

I had the Ruby gem Sass installed recently and have been frequently using it for an app I'm working on. Today I went to go run sass --watch scss:css as I normally would and noticed I got the following error:

```
-bash: sass: command not found
```

I then tried running the following line and got this output:

```
~$ sudo gem install sass

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/sass
```

I would consider myself a novice when it comes to interpreting shell/bash errors, any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

**Update**

I've since tried @jperelli's suggestion and got the following (ps I am on Mac OS):

```
~$ sudo gem update bundler

Updating installed gems
Updating bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.10.5.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/bundle
```

Comment: How is this a duplicate of that question? I asked two months ago whereas the mentioned question was asked one month ago..

Answer (score 27):

If you have still this problem, you may try:

```
$ sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass
```

I had almost the same issue (for ***compass***) with the latest update to *OS X* **El Capitan**, and it worked for me.
Just use it like this:

```
$ sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin gem_package_name
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Worked for me on MacOS Sierra 10.12.15

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you stupmed a bug in bundler itself https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1977

Try upgrading bundler and then installing sass again

```
sudo gem update bundler
sudo gem install sass
```

Alternatively, you can install sass from OS repositories

```
# assuming you use ubuntu
sudo apt-get install ruby-sass
```

Comment: This is due to lack of root access with El Capitan, not bundler itself.

Comment: This worked for me: on Fedora 30 and Centos 7

sudo dnf install rubygem-sass