# Compass doesn't work after update to OS X El Capitan (10.11)

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems, compass, osx-elcapitan

After installing **OS X El Capitan** (10.11) my ruby *compass* is no longer working. After trying to install *compass* I recieve error message like this:

```
$ sudo gem install compass
  ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
      Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/compass
```

How this can be fixed?

Comment: Hi @Leo, and welcome to SO. :-) If this is the working solution you provided, please post it as an answer to your question and accept it. This will help others with the same problem find what they're looking for easier.

Comment: Thanks Leo, but you should add the solution as an answer. Thanks again

Comment: Thumbs up to Nash comment, for the sake of clarity. Oh, and thank you! :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm still a newbie her. I fixed that. Hopefully you got resolved this issue :)

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem after upgrading to OS X El Capitan (10.11), but while trying to `sudo gem install sass`. The poster's solution of putting the path in the install command worked for me, and installing compass also installs sass, so: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass` did the trick. Thanks Leo!

Comment: I was not able to install compass with `-n` option but installing sass worked with it.

Answer (score 21):

The fix I found was simply to put the PATH in the install command for any ruby gem package:

```
$  sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin GEM_PACKAGE_NAME
```

So with *compass* it worked for me as:

```
$ sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass
```

Good Luck!

Comment: How is this any different than the existing answer?

Comment: At first I included the answer in the question. This is just a separation of the two.

Comment: Don't post duplicate answers.  [You've already posted this answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32903516/1652962).  If two questions can be answered by the same answer, they should be closed as duplicates.

Comment: Ok, 10x, it's noticed!